# Android: test conditional feature delivery based on country

Tags: android, google-play, android-bundle

I will use a dynamic feature in an android app. This feature should be available in a specific country. So I use the [country condition](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/conditional-delivery#country-condition) for the dynamic feature module:

My code:

```html
    <dist:module
        dist:title="@string/title_dynamicfeaturede">
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:install-time>
                <dist:conditions>
                    <dist:user-countries dist:exclude="false">
                        <dist:country dist:code="DE"/>
                    </dist:user-countries>
                </dist:conditions>
            </dist:install-time>
        </dist:delivery>
    </dist:module>
```

When I try to test this condition using the [bundleTool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool), the condition will be ignored. Is there any way to test this condition without using the Playstore?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't find a solution. So I decided not to use the dynamic feature. Instead I created another screen and the user has to choose the country.

Answer (score 0):

based on android doc, you should set the flag dist:user-countries dist:exclude="**true**" to set the filter on.